# Python unittest - after creating test suite with particular test all my tests are being executed

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have the following code:

```
import unittest


class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_smth(self):
        self.assertEqual(3, 2, 'buu')

class TestTwo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_smth_two(self):
        self.assertEqual(1, 2, 'buu')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTest(Test("test_smth"))
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner
    runner.run(suite)
```

I want to run only `test_smth` using `TestSuite` but my other test, `test_smth_two`, is also being executed. I am using `eclipse` with `pydev`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach: `python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method`